# Activeform field hidden on create and shown on update in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, active-form

I have an activeform field.

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'featured_listings')->dropDownList([1=>'Yes',0=>'No']); ?>
```

I need this field hidden on create and shown on update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `if()` statement which uses `$model->isNewRecord`:

```
if($model->isNewRecord) {
    //do your stuff here
}
```

Or if you want to have just HTML hidden, add proper class by `$model->isNewRecord ? 'hidden' : ''`

Comment: Is it for `hidden on create` ?

Comment: It is for not **render** field on `create`, because on `create` your model have property `isNewRecord` set to `TRUE`.

Comment: That works well. I think I have to change my submit button as well. How to add `!$model->isNewRecord` to the button   `<?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>`

Comment: `!$model->isNewRecord` ?

Comment: But what you want to change?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166310/discussion-between-paheerathan-selvarasa-and-yupik).